# Remove white space after every image in Twenty Twelve theme wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to remove the white space after each image. as shown in the website link which is found [here](http://thecommonlife.com.au/rainham/a-visit-to-waterloo-lydia-hoover/). So if anyone could please advise how can I remove this space. I'm very thankful as I'm a wordpress beginner.

Comment: One of your links does not work 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add to your `.wp-caption` CSS class this: `padding-bottom: 0px;` And the white spaces after the images are reduced to the minimum.

**EDITED:** 
For the first one, or even for all the images, you can try modifying the margin of the `<p>` contents:

```
.entry-content p{
  margin: 0 0 12px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working for all the pics except the first one, could you please check it using this link http://thecommonlife.com.au/rainham/a-visit-to-waterloo-lydia-hoover/

Comment: I've update my answer to fix the white spaces of the first image. Check it!